# How to pick a specific array position in python

Tags: python, arrays

What is the right way to match the second position in my array?

my array (d) from HID is [1,1,0,0,0,0,0] or  [1,0,0,0,0,0,0]

when position 2 is 1, I want to meet my condition.

This is what I have hacked together:

```
    while True:
        d = h.read(64)
        if d:
            for btn, val in enumerate(d):
                if btn == 1:
                    if val == 1:
                        print("Condition Finally Met")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just index directly into the list:

```
while True:
    d = h.read(64)
    if len(d) >= 2 and d[1] == 1:
        print("Condition Met")
```

In Python, lists are zero-indexed (i.e. the first item is numbered 0, not 1), so `d[1]` gets the value of the *second* item. We also check that the list actually contains at least two items, just in case.